# Tkinter PhotoClass (couldn't recognize data in image file)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to load a gif image into my tkinter GUI and I am using PhotoClass().Please note that I am not using any external modules such as PIL.I am using python 3.4. At first I tried a .png image,which is not supported natively.So I changed the image extension to .gif, which (I believe) is supported.

The image is first refrenced here:

```
img=tk.PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")
```

And is placed into a Label here:

```
ImageLabel=tk.Label(root, image=img,)
ImageLabel.grid(row=14,column=1)
```

The error I receive is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "Image.gif"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't just change the name of a PNG file and expect it to magically become a GIF file, they are quite different file formats.

Comment: When I open the image on paint the image seems to be fine.

Comment: Because paint can open many file formats. Did you just change the extension manually? Or do a "Save As"? If you changed the extension manually it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t just change the extension to magically convert a file to a different format. Tkinter is expecting GIF data, doesn’t get it, and thus throws the error that the data can’t be recognized. You must give it actual GIF data.